# App that monitors changes in a folder and reacts to them

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, monitoring

I have to write an app that, after an authentication phase, monitors the changes of a folder and when something happens (a file is added/deleted/updated) reacts by sending a notification to a server.

What is the best way to do that?

A windows service launched after the authentication?

Please note that this monitoring activity should be performed while in parallel the user is navigating the ui.

Comment: Look into the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)for monitoring the changes in the directory. you have to import `System.IO;` to your project for implementing this.

```
 FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("your directory path");
```

You can assign events according to the changes in the directory as like the following:

```
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);//<-- call OnChanged when the contents changed
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);//<-- call OnChanged when new files are created
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);//<-- call OnChanged when any file is deleted
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);//<-- call OnChanged when any file is renamed

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
       // Define your method here
    }
```